# IndexOf array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

I have an array with objects. I tried `indexOf` but it doesn't work.

```js
let tags = [];

let tag = {
  text: "hello",
  element: document.createElement('span')
};
tags.push(tag);

console.log(tags.indexOf("hello"));
```

I was trying something like that, tags have some values i just don't want to add all the code.

Is there a solution to do that, to compare only the text from the array with a string, in a few lines?

Comment: That's not an array.

Comment: That's an object.

Comment: I edited, i missed the array sorry

Comment: Try `tags.filter(tag => tag.text === 'hello')`

Comment: What kind of syntax is `let tags[];`? Why would you think that `indexOf` called on a string like `hello` would somehow match an element which was an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` to filter out tag which have your given text.

```js
let tags = [{
        text: 'hello',
        element: document.createElement('span')
}, {
        text: 'there',
        element: document.createElement('div')
}, {
        text: 'world',
        element: document.createElement('span')
}, {
        text: 'hello',
        element: document.createElement('span')
}];

let result = tags.filter(tag => tag.text === 'hello');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer returns an array that contains all the tags which pass the filter function. But the original question seems to be asking for a way to find the index of a particular tag. You can use `Array.prototype.findIndex`, which accepts a function to test with:

```
tags.findIndex(tag => tag.text === 'hello')
```

Comment: The real question was, I wanted a function to test if the tag already exists in the array of objects. My question was poorly worded. But yeah thank you too for your answer !